# R shiny server: how to update scripts with multiple users and sessions?

Tags: r, server, shiny, updates

We run an R shiny server (R:  3.5.1, Shiny: 1.0.3) on a virtual machine under CentOS. We are experiemcing some issues with script updates to the server.
We find that under certain conditions if we update a script to the server it may take some time (up to days occassionally) for the updated script to be actually executed.
From experience, this delay only occurs when the srcipt has multiple users. Scripts that have a sningle user (me) update instantly as soon as the updated scripts have been written to the server.
This makes sense: as long as users are running the scripts in sessions, you cannot update it. We know that resetting the Shniy server does the trick but this strikes me as a crude way of resolving this issue.
As I am not a linux expert I do not know if this is caused by Shiny or by Linux.
Does anyone know where this behaviour is documented so I can learn how to better control the process of updating?

Comment: I would suggest reading over the shiny server documentation: http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/ Maybe ask on community.rstudio.com's shiny channel.

Comment: Thanks! Section 3.1.1. states: Fortunately, Shiny applications generally do not need to be restarted when changes to ui.R or server.R are made, as Shiny will check for changes to these files on page load.
In my case changes to ui.R and server.R are delayed.

Comment: 1) Create App restart button which only be shown to admin, that stops the app 
2) You physically need to add some changes to the directorywhere the shinyapp is located , hence the creators recommend you recreate the restart.txt file, by `touch restart.txt`
3) Add session timeout to your apps, which will kick people out if they haven't used the app in lets say last few mins

Comment: More than one year later and it has become clear to me that the use of global.R creates, as per the scoping rules, global object even across multiple sessions. My interpretation and experience is that such objects cannot be changed as long as there are active shiny sessions. This results in a situation that updating the code on the R server may not be effectuated until all sessions have terminated or until the server has been restarted.
I have become more careful in the use of global.R and prefer to source a script with another name to avoid this mechanism for instance data_processing.R.